# Gitlab not creating repositories in gitolite

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I've installed Gitlab with Gitolite and configured as the instructions says.

The users keys added by gitlab app are saved in `.gitolite/conf/keydir`, just like should be, I guess.

After create my projects in app, I tried to push in them, and found out that haven't being created any repo in git user.

In the install, we have the following check: `bundle exec rake gitlab:app:status RAILS_ENV=production` which resulted 'YES ' for all the checks.

But then when we create a project, and make the same check the result was:

```
...
.....YES
......YES
UMASK for .gitolite.rc is 0007? ............YES
/home/git/.gitolite/hooks/common/post-receive exists? ............YES
Validating projects repositories:
Gerência de Notebooks.....post-receive file missing
rake aborted!
```

I'm using gl-v304.

What could be occurring ?

My git and gitolite users are passwordless

For the installation, I had to set my sshd_config with `PermitEmptyPasswords yes`, for the git user save the gitlab sshkey, and after config back sshd_config to `PermitEmptyPasswords no`, when cloned for test it works perfectly, or almost.

just hope you can help guys, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but here goes anyway:

Which version of *redis-server* do you have? Older version than 2.4 causes problems like this.
Try upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

You got to add this on gitlab installation

```
 git config --global user.name Gitlab
 git config --global user.email gitlab@localhost
```

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1904#issuecomment-10647145